# Php-imap_open-How can I show a link to save attachment, without save files on server?

Tags: php, imap

I tried to fetchbody to read emails from imap_open connection.

I can read the text of the mail and I can save all attachments on my Webserver.
But I want to create a link for everyone  attachment-file, to download the files directly from the mail-Server, without save files on my Webserver.

I want:
Link—>Download—>direct from Mail-Server

At this moment:
Save all attachments on my Webserver—> link to each file on my Webserver—> Download attachments from my Webserver

```
<?php

If ((Isset($_POST['uid']) == false) or (Isset($_POST['user']) == false) or (Isset($_POST['pw']) == false)) {
        echo ("Keine Zuordnung vorhanden");
    return;
}

function getAttachments($imap, $mailNum, $part, $partNum) {
    $attachments = array();

    if (isset($part->parts)) {
        foreach ($part->parts as $key => $subpart) {
            if($partNum != "") {
                $newPartNum = $partNum . "." . ($key + 1);
            }
            else {
                $newPartNum = ($key+1);
            }
            $result = getAttachments($imap, $mailNum, $subpart,
                $newPartNum);
            if (count($result) != 0) {
                 array_push($attachments, $result);
             }
        }
    }
    else if (isset($part->disposition)) {
        // print_r($part);
        if (strtoupper($part->disposition) == "ATTACHMENT") {
            $partStruct = imap_bodystruct($imap, $mailNum, $partNum);
            $attachmentDetails = array(
                "name"    => $part->dparameters[0]->value,
                "subtype" => $partStruct->subtype,
                "partNum" => $partNum,
                "enc"     => $partStruct->encoding
            );
            return $attachmentDetails;
        }
    }

    return $attachments;
}






 function getPartList($struct, $base="") {
    $res=Array();
    if (!property_exists($struct,"parts")) {
            return [$base?:"0"];
    } else {
            $num=1;
            if (count($struct->parts)==1) return getPartList($struct->parts[0], $base);

            foreach ($struct->parts as $p=>$part) {
                    foreach (getPartList($part, $p+1) as $subpart) {
                            $res[]=($base?"$base.":"").$subpart;
                    }
            }
    }
    return $res;
 }






$username = $_POST['user'] ;
$pw = $_POST['pw'];
$server_in = $_POST['server'];
$port = $_POST['port'];
$uid = $_POST['uid'];
$msgno = $_POST['msgno'];




$imap= imap_open($server_in, $username, $pw);
 $msgno = imap_msgno($imap, $uid);
$nachrichten_struktur = imap_fetchstructure($imap, $uid, FT_UID);

$kodierung = $nachrichten_struktur->encoding;
$nachrichten_type = $nachrichten_struktur->type;
$res=getPartList($nachrichten_struktur);



if ($nachrichten_type == 0){
$text = quoted_printable_decode(imap_fetchbody($imap, $msgno ,1));
}
else if ($nachrichten_type == 1){
if(count($res) <=2){
    $text = quoted_printable_decode(imap_fetchbody($imap, $msgno , 2));
}
else if(count($res) >=3){
    $text = quoted_printable_decode(imap_fetchbody($imap, $msgno , 2.2));
}
}
else{
    $text = imap_fetchbody($imap, $msgno ,1);
}


switch ($kodierung) {
    # 7BIT
    case 0:
        $body =  $text;
    # 8BIT
    case 1:
        $body = quoted_printable_decode(imap_8bit($text));
    # BINARY
    case 2:
        $body = imap_binary($text);
    # BASE64
    case 3:
        $body = imap_base64($text);
    # QUOTED-PRINTABLE
    case 4:
        $body = quoted_printable_decode($text);
    # OTHER
    case 5:
        $body = $text;
    # UNKNOWN
    default:
       $body = $text;
}

//attachmentDetails
$attachments = getAttachments($imap, $msgno, $nachrichten_struktur, "");


$body .= "<br />Attachments: ";
$body .=  "<ul>";
foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {  
    $body .= '<li><a href="test_imap_download.php?func=' . $func . '&folder=' . $folder . '&uid=' . $uid .'&part=' . $attachment["partNum"] . '&enc=' . $attachment["enc"] . '">' .$attachment["name"] . "</a></li>";
}
$body .= "</ul>";



echo $body;

imap_close($imap);








?>
```

Comment: Please show us your code and we might be able to help you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I edited my post and add my code

Comment: @Newbie If you want to delete your post, then do that.  Otherwise please do not destroy it in the way you did previously, as this site is meant as a repository of knowledge.  If you solved your question, then posting an answer is fine as well, as is accepting it.

Comment: Do you get any error? I can't see that $func or $folder is defined anywhere in your code.

Comment: That’s right. I will post the correct code.

Comment: Why did I get two negative points?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but i hadn't soo much time last few days. 
I solved my problem. The right way is:
Read Email, check attachments -> write a submit link for every attachment file, AND input hidden filed which has part_number and uid_number -> click on link, send form to php file -> php file read attachment from webserver and give it back via content type:
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download");

My read file:

....

```
function getAttachments($imap, $mailNum, $part, $partNum) {
    $attachments = array();

    if (isset($part->parts)) {
        foreach ($part->parts as $key => $subpart) {
            if($partNum != "") {
                $newPartNum = $partNum . "." . ($key + 1);
            }
            else {
                $newPartNum = ($key+1);
            }
            $result = getAttachments($imap, $mailNum, $subpart,
                $newPartNum);
            if (count($result) != 0) {
                 array_push($attachments, $result);
             }
        }
    }
    else if (isset($part->disposition)) {
        // print_r($part);
        if (strtoupper($part->disposition) == "ATTACHMENT") {
            $partStruct = imap_bodystruct($imap, $mailNum, $partNum);
            $attachmentDetails = array(
                "name"    => $part->dparameters[0]->value,
                "subtype" => $partStruct->subtype,
                "partNum" => $partNum,
                "enc"     => $partStruct->encoding
            );
            return $attachmentDetails;
        }
    }

    return $attachments;
}








 function getPartList($struct, $base="") {
    $res=Array();
    if (!property_exists($struct,"parts")) {
            return [$base?:"0"];
    } else {
            $num=1;
            if (count($struct->parts)==1) return getPartList($struct->parts[0], $base);

            foreach ($struct->parts as $p=>$part) {
                    foreach (getPartList($part, $p+1) as $subpart) {
                            $res[]=($base?"$base.":"").$subpart;
                    }
            }
    }
    return $res;
 }



$imap= imap_open($server_in, $username, $pw);
 $msgno = imap_msgno($imap, $uid);
$nachrichten_struktur = imap_fetchstructure($imap, $uid, FT_UID);

$kodierung = $nachrichten_struktur->encoding;
$nachrichten_type = $nachrichten_struktur->type;
$res=getPartList($nachrichten_struktur);
$subtype = $nachrichten_struktur->subtype;



if ($nachrichten_type == 0){
$text = quoted_printable_decode(imap_fetchbody($imap, $msgno ,1));
}
else if ($nachrichten_type == 1){
if(count($res) <=2){
    if ($subtype == "MIXED"){
    $text = quoted_printable_decode(imap_fetchbody($imap, $msgno , 1)); 
    }
    else{
    $text = quoted_printable_decode(imap_fetchbody($imap, $msgno , 2));
    }
}
else if(count($res) >=3){
    $text = quoted_printable_decode(imap_fetchbody($imap, $msgno , 1));
}
}
else{
    $text = imap_fetchbody($imap, $msgno ,1);
}


switch ($kodierung) {
    # 7BIT
    case 0:
        $body =  $text;
    # 8BIT
    case 1:
        $body = quoted_printable_decode(imap_8bit($text));
    # BINARY
    case 2:
        $body = imap_binary($text);
    # BASE64
    case 3:
        $body = imap_base64($text);
    # QUOTED-PRINTABLE
    case 4:
        $body = quoted_printable_decode($text);
    # OTHER
    case 5:
        $body = $text;
    # UNKNOWN
    default:
       $body = $text;
}

//attachmentDetails
$attachments = getAttachments($imap, $msgno, $nachrichten_struktur, "");

if(count($attachments) > 0){
$body .= "<br />Attachments: <br /> ";
}
foreach ($attachments as $attachment) { 
$body .=  "<span style='display:inline-block; margin-right:1%;'><form class='form_download_attachment' action='src/php/download_attach.php' method='POST' target='_blank'>";
    $body .= "<input type='hidden' name='uid' value='".$uid."'>";
    $body .= "<input type='hidden' name='data-attachment_partNum' value='".$attachment["partNum"]."'>";
    $body .= "<input type='hidden' name='data-enc' value='".$attachment["enc"]."'>";
    //$body .= "<input type='hidden' name='server' value='".$server_in."'>";
    //$body .= "<input type='hidden' name='user' value='".$username."'>";
    //$body .= "<input type='hidden' name='pw' value='".$pw."'>";
    $body .= '<button type="submit" class="attachment_download btn btn-warning btn-sm" >' .$attachment["name"] . "</button>";
    $body .= "</form></span>";
}
```

....

my download file:

...

```
$imap_open= imap_open($get_server_in, $get_username, $get_pw);
$msgno = imap_msgno($imap_open, $get_uid);


function downloadAttachment($imap, $uid, $partNum, $encoding) {
    $partStruct = imap_bodystruct($imap, imap_msgno($imap, $uid), $partNum);
$filesize = $partStruct->bytes;
$filename = $partStruct->dparameters[0]->value;

    $message = imap_fetchbody($imap, $uid, $partNum, FT_UID);

    switch ($encoding) {
        case 0:
        case 1:
            $message = imap_8bit($message);
            break;
        case 2:
            $message = imap_binary($message);
            break;
        case 3:
            $message = imap_base64($message);
            break;
        case 4:
            $message = quoted_printable_decode($message);
            break;
    }


    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
    header("Content-Type: application/download");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $filename);
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    if ($_SESSION['mobile'] != "true"){
    header("Content-Length: ".$filesize);
    }
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate");
    header("Pragma: public");
    echo $message;


}

downloadAttachment($imap_open, $get_uid, $get_partNum, $get_encoding);
```

...

Thank for your help!